# Whats wrong with this scala tuple?

Tags: scala

Trying to create a method that determines if a set is a subset of another set, both given as parameters. When I tried to test it the console printed out

scala.MatchError : (List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7),List(1, 2, 3, 4)) (of class scala.Tuple2),

the two lists given are what I was using as parameters to test it. Also, scala was making me type out return in front of true and false, any ideas what led to this either?

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean ={
(a,b) match {
    case (_,Nil)=> return true
  }
  b match {
    case h::t if (a.contains(h)) => subset(a,t)
    case h::t => return false
  }}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers don't really answer exactly *why* your code is incorrect. It appears that you're handling the case when list `b` is empty  and non-empty and that everything should be okay, but in fact you're actually not. Let's look at your code again, with some formatting fixes.

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = {
  (a, b) match {
     case (_, Nil) => return true
  } // we can never make it past here, because either we return true,
    // or a MatchError is raised.

  b match {
    case h :: t if (a.contains(h)) => subset(a,t)
    case h :: t => return false
  }
}
```

The real problem here is that you have two completely disconnected `match` statements. So when `b` is non-empty, the first match will fail, because it only handles the case when `b` is `Nil`.

As pointed out in the other solutions, the proper way to do this is to merge the two `match` statements together into one.

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = {
    (a, b) match {
        case (_, Nil) => true
        case (xs, head :: tail) if(xs contains head) => subset(xs, tail)
        case _ => false
    }
}
```

Notice how the `return` statements are no longer needed. In scala you should avoid using `return` as much as possible, as it's likely that your way of thinking around `return` actually lead you into this trap. Methods that return early are likely to lead to bugs, and are difficult to read.

A cleaner way to implement this could use `diff`. `b` can be considered a subset of `a` if the set of elements of `b` minus the elements of `a` is empty.

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = (b.distinct diff a.distinct).nonEmpty
```

`distinct` is only required if it's possible for `a` and `b` to contain duplicates, because we're trying a `List` like a `Set` when it's actually not.

Better yet, if we convert the `List`s to `Set`s, then we can use `subsetOf`.

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = b.toSet.subsetOf(a.toSet)
```

Comment: Note that a more sophisticated type system could realize that only non-Nil cases of `b` escape the first match.

Answer (score 1):

Scala match expression should match to at least one case expression. Otherwise the MatchError is raised.

You should have used the following cases:

```
(a, b) match {
  case (_, Nil) => true
  case (aa, h :: t) if aa contains h => subset(aa, t)
  case _ => false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way could be to call methods in standard library.

For each element in 'b', check if 'a' contains that element.

Here is the simple code:

```
def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = {
  (b.forall(a.contains(_)))
}
```

Comment: what this noise of if-else's and returns is for? just def subset() = b.forall....

Comment: @JiříVypědřík You are absolutely right! Changed the code. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

MatchError - `This class implements errors which are thrown whenever an object doesn't match any pattern of a pattern matching expression.`

Obviously the second list having elements in it will cause this error, as no pattern will match. You should just add another branch to the first `match` like so:

```
    def subset(a: List[Int], b: List[Int]): Boolean = {
      (a, b) match {
        case (_, List()) => return true
        case _ => b match {
          case h :: t if (a.contains(h)) => subset(a, t)
          case h :: t => return false
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

MatchError occurs whenever an object doesn't match any pattern of a pattern matching expression.

An alternative way is by using `dropWhile` or `takeWhile`

```
def subsets(a:List[Int], b:List[Int]):Boolean = {
return b.dropWhile { ele => a.contains(ele)}.size==0
}
```

OR

```
def subsets(a:List[Int], b:List[Int]):Boolean = {
return b.takeWhile { ele => a.contains(ele)}.size==b.size
}
```